# Comparing words for resistance

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison

The English word "resistance" is obviously etymologically related to *resistentia*, and I would like to understand how good of a translation *resistentia*.
To be clear, I mean resistance in the sense of a rebellious movement, strong opposition to present rule, or something similar.
There are several words in L&S which translate to "resistance" or "opposition":

- [*oppugnantia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=oppugnantia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)
- [*refragatio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=refragatio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)
- [*refragium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=refragium&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)
- [*repugnantia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DR%3Aentry+group%3D20)
- [*repugnatio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DR%3Aentry+group%3D20%3Aentry%3Drepugnatio)
- [*resistentia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=resistentia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)

Based on the dictionary entries, I don't see much of a difference between these.
Are there differences, or are they pretty much interchangeable?
Does the extant text corpus suggest notable differences in tone or style?

Judging by intuition — which is known to have failed miserably — I see a distinction into three categories:
The ones coming from *pugna* refer to armed resistance.
The ones coming from *refragari* I don't understand; I don't see where they come from so that I could see what kind of a nuance they might have.
Finally *resistentia* sounds like standing against something, suggesting a different tone from the more militant words.
I have no proof to substantiate my guesswork, and I might be reading too much into things.
However, I do think that the *pugna*-words mean essentially the same thing, and so do the *refragari*-words; the question is then whether these three classes differ from each other.

L&S mentions that *resistentia* is a late Latin word for *repugnantia*, so those seem to be synonyms.
Otherwise I find the entries hard to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *refragor* has the meaning of resisting, opposing or gainsaying; *refragator* is an opponent; *refragatio* is resistance or opposition. Another likely verb is *renitor*, to struggle against, or resist (there is a derived noun *renisus*, which is post-classical).

I believe that verbs that are compounds of *sto* — *resto*, *resisto*, *obsto*, *obsisto* — and their derived nouns contain the idea of 'standing one's ground': as it seems to me, they do not quite have the sense of active resistance as conducted by the French *maquis* in WW2, for example.

Answer (score 1):

"Repugnantia" etc. is more like fighting back, actively opposing something, or rejecting it; whereas "resistentia" is endurance, not yielding to a pressure. Oppugnantia is like rising against, or standing in the way of, something. "Repugnantia" also means intrinsic contradiction or incoherence. "Repugnatio" is rather rare and I have never seen it to mean "contradiction". The -io verbal nouns tend to have more concrete and verbal meaning, whereas the "-ntia" nouns are often more abstract and de-verbalized: cf. e.g. "provisio" vs. "providentia". So I thing "repugnatio" would tend to be used to refer to the actual occurrent acts of resistance, whereas "repugnantia" would describe the general attitude or programme as a whole.